# Issue with configure phone gap for android

Tags: android, cordova

I need to conver HTML 5 to android app.
I downloaded phonegap and eclipse and android.
I can run the emulator . Where i need to put the extarcted content to use phonegap with android.

Comment: read the documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information here

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

and here

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_project-settings_index.md.html#Project%20Settings